# Is there a way to grab probablities of my qubits in Q#?

Tags: programming, q#

https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/grover.html
I am looking for a visual, or just probabilities like the ones given in the link.Is this possible on Q#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DumpMachine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.diagnostics.dumpmachine) to dump the amplitudes and probabilities of the states; for Grover search it will give you something like this:

[image]

Comment: I am just realizing the qubits are integers. I am not used to this notation... What are these qubits representative of?